# Slow git server under TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, msysgit

We run git server inside TFS 2013. If we do server interactions under Visual Studio 2013, everything is fine. When we try to do this under SourceTree, everything slows down to a few minutes for a simple pull or push.

When I try to run `git pull` using msysgit, it let's me wait for a long time, then asks for credentials, then it says `Already up-to-day.` quickly. It seems like the problem is authentication, but other Windows-authenticated services run quickly.

Mysteriously, sometimes (for a day or so) there is no lag. The server is not loaded significantly, though, and the behaviour is very "binary" -- user waits for a long time, or not at all.

Do you have any idea what may be the cause or how to debug this?

More information:

So, I checked Event Viewer to search for `UploadPackHandler` events. After seeing many of these logs, I incline to form a hypothesis that slow `ExecutionTime` happens iff `IdentityName` is `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`, not domain/username.

I also checked IIS authentication settings for `tfs` application: `Anounymous Authentication`, `ASP.NET Impersonation` and `Forms Authentication` are disabled, `Windows Authentication` is enabled with the `401 Challenge` response type.

Partical export from log (I replaced actual domain name and actual user names of commiters by DOMAIN\user.name):

```
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9346962
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 119581
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 436339
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9736610
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9402685
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 46005
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 196938
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 31824
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9353293
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 105786
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 80147
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 342590
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9623900
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 267121
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 231667
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 312517
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9565790
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9565456
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 58273
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 36315
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 371034
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 8407753
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 8691577
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9909680
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 63776
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 238929
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 768842
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 224812
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9001033
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 51920
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 8278389
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 245677
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 51172
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9102215
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 79980
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 135117
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9355631
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 50953
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 76634
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9175315
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 8410089
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 71521
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 49370
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 139672
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9013338
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 133349
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 144205
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 9358247
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 8355487
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 30206
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 22815
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 550557
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 8957801
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 46096
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 113288
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 8893750
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 150581
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 185564
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 8420761
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 12861852
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: DOMAIN\user.name, ExecutionTime: 449174
UploadPackHandler: IdentityName: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, ExecutionTime: 14223664
```

Comment: Try this: http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/ to store your credentials. It might help.

Comment: That's definitely a handy utility, thanks! But it doesn't solve this problem -- git fetch now just waits and then uses the stored credentials.

Comment: Do you have any other authentication types enabled in IIS where the Git repository is being served up? I wonder if there's a long running failed authentication occurring before trying NTLM authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the question -- I looked into it and updated question accordingly.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your somewhere in your git settings the username is configured as the network service. Have you tried running this commands under a different user on your machine?